# CommandTimeout seems to have no effect Queries still timing out after 30 seconds

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, vb.net, timeout

Our production database as grown to a size where several of our longer running stored procedures are taking more than the default 30 seconds to complete.  I've programatically set some of the CommandTimeouts on the command objects but the calls to the store procedures still appear to be timing out after 30 seconds.

Here's what I did:

1. In web.config set this property

   *add key="CommandTimeOut" value="180"*
2. Added this to the top of my class that needs the timeout set:

   *Dim COMMAND_TIMEOUT As Integer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CommandTimeOut")*
3. After creating the command object set the timeout property on the object.

   *cmd.CommandTimeout = COMMAND_TIMEOUT*

Unfortunately my stored procedures still seem to be timing out when they take longer than 30 seconds to execute.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And you're sure your code is over-riding the default?

Comment: There are also Transaction Timeouts as well, which may be coming into play. When I ran into this problem before the Transaction Timeouts (we were using a TransactionScope) were the ultimate culprit.

Comment: I assume I am overriding the default, you can see from my comment exactly what I've done and I've debugged the code to ensure the variables were set correctly.  Not sure why it wouldn't be overriding the default.

Comment: Are you sure it's a command timeout and not a connection time out?  Can you post the actual exception you are getting?

Comment: The error is definitely being thrown on the "execute" line of the _Using reader As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()_ line.  I don't think it's a connection issue otherwise I'd be having issues with other parts of the application and I'm not.

Comment: Set CommandTimeout to ZERO (0) to make it wait indefinitely and see if that throws an error too. `A value of 0 indications no limit, and should be avoided in a CommandTimeout because an attempt to execute a command will wait indefinitely.` *I'm not advising to leave it at zero, I'm just saying to TEST with zero just to see if it also ignores this setting.*

Comment: Whats your connectionstring? Please paste the entire string, but replace secret parts (username, passsword, ip, etc) with XXXX :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the Transaction and Connection timeouts are set with more than 30 seconds...

Hope this can helps,

Bye

cghersi